# How to obtain outputs that are from future in a keras sequential model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, finance, stock

i'm a beginner in python and i'm interested in machine learning attached to finance. I have created a model to predict future prices reading from a csv file, I have created the neural network, I get it to have very little loss but the outputs cannot be extracted or I just haven't created the necessary layers.
I would greatly appreciate a help with this. Thanks in advance.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(1,1)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=30, batch_size=1, verbose=1)
score = model.evaluate(train_x, train_y, verbose=0)
print('Keras model loss = ', score[0])
print('Keras model accuracy = ', score[1])
   

train_predictions = model.predict(train_x)
test_predictions = model.predict(test_x)

train_predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(train_predictions)
train_y = scaler.inverse_transform([train_y])

train_predict_plot = np.empty_like(scaled_data)
train_predict_plot[:,:] = np.nan
train_predict_plot[1:len(train_predictions)+1, :] = train_predictions

test_predict_plot = np.empty_like(scaled_data)
test_predict_plot[:,:] = np.nan
test_predict_plot[

plt.plot(scaler.inverse_transform(scaled_data))
plt.plot(train_predict_plot)
plt.plot(test_predict_plot)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you explain what issues you are facing? _"but the outputs cannot be extracted or I just haven't created the necessary layers"_ doesn't really mean anything

Comment: What I am trying to solve are not issues but to obtain the outputs of this model that uses a csv file with the time in hours and the closing price of an asset, for example obtain a prediction for the next 10 hours in the future, the question would be, what function should I use to achieve it?